# Removing header index from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`):

```
       0       1         2            3                    4     5
0   6894   JONES     STEVE            D  2017-01-03 00:00:00  None
1  13555   SMITH     JENNY            E  2017-04-01 00:00:00  None
```

I have a header called `new_header` that I am applying to the data-frame which looks like:

```
0                     Identifier
1                        Surname
2                  First name(s)
3                 Transferred to
4                  Transfer Date
5                         Status
```

I apply `new_header` with the following:

```
df.columns = new_header
```

and I get the following output:

```
0               Identifier Surname  ...          Transfer Date Status
0                     6894   JONES  ...    2017-01-03 00:00:00   None
1                    13555   SMITH  ...    2017-04-01 00:00:00   None
```

In the top left corner of `df` you can see a `0`.  How can I remove the 0 so my data-frame looks like:

```
                Identifier Surname  ...          Transfer Date Status
0                     6494   JONES  ...    2017-01-03 00:00:00   None
1                    13595   SMITH  ...    2017-04-01 00:00:00   None
```

Comment: what if you do `df.columns = new_header.values` ?

Comment: df.columns.name = None should do it

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to rename columns with a `pandas.Series` object.  When doing so, the name of the `Series` translates to the name of the resulting `pandas.Index` object.  You can solve this in various ways.

#### Assign to `df.columns` something that doesn't have a name as suggested by [@anky_91](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062828/removing-header-index-from-dataframe#comment98765732_56062828)

```
df.columns = new_header.values

df

   Identifier Surname First name(s) Transferred to        Transfer Date Status
0        6894   JONES         STEVE              D  2017-01-03 00:00:00   None
1       13555   SMITH         JENNY              E  2017-04-01 00:00:00   None
```

---

#### Assign to `df.columns` a series whose name is `None`

```
df.columns = new_header.rename(None)

df

   Identifier Surname First name(s) Transferred to        Transfer Date Status
0        6894   JONES         STEVE              D  2017-01-03 00:00:00   None
1       13555   SMITH         JENNY              E  2017-04-01 00:00:00   None
```

---

#### Rename the axis after the fact

```
df.columns = new_header
df.rename_axis(None, 1)

   Identifier Surname First name(s) Transferred to        Transfer Date Status
0        6894   JONES         STEVE              D  2017-01-03 00:00:00   None
1       13555   SMITH         JENNY              E  2017-04-01 00:00:00   None
```

---

#### Use `rename` with the `new_header` as a renaming mapping

This assumes the index of `new_header` lines up with what is being renamed in `df`.
Also, I had to get tricky and make sure that they were the same type.

```
df.rename(columns=int).rename(columns=new_header)

   Identifier Surname First name(s) Transferred to        Transfer Date Status
0        6894   JONES         STEVE              D  2017-01-03 00:00:00   None
1       13555   SMITH         JENNY              E  2017-04-01 00:00:00   None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get or set the index by name

```
df.index.name = ''
```

see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.name.html)